# Create user by passing user name from psql command and use it in SQL file

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I want that the variable user that I set in psql statement, the user should be created in POSTGRES database with that variable value.

Psql statement:

```
psql -h $ Hostname -p $Port -d $databaseName -U $admin -v USER = $MyUser -v PASSWORD= $My_Password -f $current_dir/createUser.sql
```

My sql script file which above command is reffering:

```
Do $createUser$
BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user where username = ':USER') THEN
    CREATE USER ':USER' WITH PASSWORD ':PASSWORD';
END $createUser$
```

It throws syntax error at or near "':USER'". Or it is not able to refer the variable in select statement as well.

I tried using :USER, :'USER' and ':USER'. But nothing worked

Comment: There is no view or table named `pg_catalog_user` in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Something creates variables $Port, $databaseName, $admin, $MyUser, $My_Password
# of they are already in the environment

sqlfile="$current_dir"/createUser.sql

cat << SQLFILE >"$sqlfile"
Do \$createUser\$
BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user where username = ':USER') THEN
    CREATE USER '$MyUser' WITH PASSWORD '$My_Password';
END \$createUser\$
SQLFILE

psql -h $ Hostname -p "$Port" -d "$databaseName" -U "$admin" -v USER = "$MyUser" -v PASSWORD = "$My_Password" -f "$sqlfile"

rm -f "$sqlfile"
```

- The variables need to be created in that script, or already exist in the environment.
- Create your sql script file using the script, so you can use the variables.
- You could use `mktemp` to create a temp file for your sql code.
- Make sure you delete the file since the password will be stored into it.
- Make sure permissions on the sql file are very limited to prevent other users from reading your user - password.
- It would be better, IMHO, to send the sql code directly "into" psql and not use a file at all.